# selecting R data.table columns representing integers

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table looking like this:

```
dd <- data.table(a= 1:3, `1990` = 4:6, `1991` = 7:9, `1992` = 10:12)
```

I want to select columns that essentially correspond to integers.

The following code would work if `dd` is a data.frame but fails if `dd` is a data.table

```
dd[,as.character(1990:1992)]
```

The following does not work either:

```
dd[,.(1990:1992)]
```

Is there a solution that mimics the data.frame solution mentioned?

Comment: You need to use `.SDcols`, i.e. `cols <- as.character(1990:1992); dd[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: To select columns whose name consist only of numbers: `dd[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^[0-9]+$")] `